# When you factory reset Windows, does it clear the Pagefile?

Tags: windows

What happens to the contents of the Pagefile when someone resets their PC? Looking for windows related answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reset your computer, the disk's file-table gets erased and
re-initialized to the factory state.

This will erase the file-table pointer to the pagefile, but the contents
will only be erased for an SSD. For an HDD, the contents may still
exist on the disk in some unallocated (yet) space, if that space on the
disk wasn't overwritten by the reset and when a new pagefile was
allocated by the newly-installed Windows.

However, even if the contents still exist on the HDD, finding them
and using them is a very big and complicated task.

Comment: I’m guessing that Pagefile isn’t recoverable for an SSD due to TRIM? 

If so, does that mean that as soon as you reset a pc with an SSD, the TRIM command instantly runs and no data is able to be recovered?

Comment: Yes. It gets TRIMed so that future write are done in one operation. Non-TRIMed pages need to be read first, modified and then written, so this is much more efficient.

Comment: The pagefile is located as C:\pagefile.sys so when you reinstall windows, that is being deleted and recreated.

Answer (score 0):

When you factory reset the computer, the Page File is gone. It gets reset as well.

Been there and done that.

Be very certain you do not need the page file before resetting.